# How to plot latitude/longitude points over netcdf map

Tags: r, plot, coordinates, netcdf

I have read in a netcdf file of observed climate data (global surface temperature) to R and would like to plot some species locality data (latitude/longitude coordinate points) over the top of this but am having difficulties doing so.

I have generated my map of temperature using:

```
obsula.pdclann <- open.ncdf("obsula.pdclann.nc")

temp_var <- "temp_mm_1_5m"

temp <- get.var.ncdf(obsula.pdclann, varid=temp_var)

image.plot(temp)
```

My species occurrence data are read in via the following:

```
speciesall <- read.table("C:/Users/Waterson/Documents/UOB/Data/speciesData/P.subrufa.txt", header=T, sep="\t")

coordinates <- cbind(speciesall$longitude, speciesall$latitude)
```

I have then created a SpatialPointsDataFrame with the coordinates:

```
speciesall_df <- SpatialPointsDataFrame(coordinates, speciesall, proj4string=CRS("+proj=longlat +ellps=WGS84"))
```

Now I am unsure of how I go about combining the point data with the netcdf map?

Comment: Simply `plot(speciesall_df, col=2, add=T)`?

Comment: Thanks, I have tried that and it doesn't return an error message but I am not able to see my points on the map.

Comment: Is there a way of reducing the lat/long extent of the netcdf map that is plotted? My species occurrence data are just in Africa so I wonder if this is why I am not able to see the point data? Thanks for your help!

Comment: Your points should be visible if they are in the same extent as your image. Check `world(); image.plot(temp, add=T); plot(speciesall_df, add=T, col=2)` to see how both datasets align.

Comment: Thanks - I am able to plot world and the data points fine, but when using image.plot(temp, add=T) the legend of the temperature plot comes up but nothing else - this is what I used:

Comment: > world()
> image.plot(temp_uk, add=T)
> plot(speciesall_df, add=T, col=2)
> extent(world)
class       : Extent 
xmin        : -179.9572 
xmax        : 190.2908 
ymin        : -59.46889 
ymax        : 69.86917 
> extent(temp_uk)
Error in .local(x, ...) : matrix should not have more than 2 columns
> extent(speciesall_df)
class       : Extent 
xmin        : -119.5969 
xmax        : 47.14225 
ymin        : -34.11667 
ymax        : 37.34 
> class(temp_uk)
[1] "matrix"

Comment: That means your `temp_uk` is missing coordinate information. You have to add those in order to plot the data correctly. Try to extract the coordinates from the NetCDF file and plot like `image.plot(x=lon, y=lat, z=temp_uk)`.

Comment: Thanks for your help, I have tried using the following but keep getting an error message  - is get.var.ncdf the command you would recommend for adding the long/lat values?

Comment: > get.var.ncdf(obsula.pdclann, varid="longitude")
Error in R_nc_get_vara_double: Invalid argument
Var: longitude  Ndims: 1   Start: 0Count: 2160Error in get.var.ncdf(obsula.pdclann, varid = "longitude") : 
  C function R_nc_get_vara_double returned error

Comment: The file structure looks like this if that helps -

Comment: > obsula.pdclann
[1] "file obsula.pdclann.nc has 4 dimensions:"
[1] "longitude   Size: 2160"
[1] "latitude   Size: 1080"
[1] "surface   Size: 1"
[1] "t   Size: 1"
[1] "------------------------"
[1] "file obsula.pdclann.nc has 12 variables:"

Comment: Try `get.var.ncdf(obsula.pdclann, varid='longitude', start=1, count=-1)`. Is it a large file? Do you have the opportunity to upload it somewhere so I can have a look at it?

Comment: Thanks - also get the same error with that: Error in R_nc_get_vara_double: Invalid argument
Var: longitude  Ndims: 1   Start: 0Count: 2160Error in get.var.ncdf(obsula.pdclann, varid = "longitude", start = 1,  : 
  C function R_nc_get_vara_double returned error

Comment: I will see if it is possible to upload the file!

Comment: Unfortnately I cannot upload it as I do not own the right to the climate model..are there any other details of the file that might be useful to look at? Thanks for your help

Comment: I'm afraid I can't help you any further than. Download ncBrowse to look at your NetCDF file. Perhaps you can figure out the lat/lon extent that way and recreate the coordinates in R (http://www.epic.noaa.gov/java/ncBrowse/).